# How to get weights from tensorflow fully_connected with Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to extract the weights from a model after training it. Here's a code.
1- how to save the model in the previously uploaded directory path?
2. how to get weights?
3. I have some csv file as the same used for modeling but without class. how can I estimate the classes with this model?

```
# Preprocess
import pandas as pd
import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Prepare data
churn = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling3.csv')
# split data into train and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(churn.iloc[:,0:10],churn.iloc[:, 10], test_size=0.2)                    
# Create a Model
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
# Input layer
model.add(Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid,input_dim=x_train.shape[1]))
# Hidden layers
model.add(Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
model.add(Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
# Output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
# Compile the Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile( optimizer= 'sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=128,validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
# ٍEvaluate the Model
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

Comment: You can use [save model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) from tensorflow and then download the model from colab [see](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=hauvGV4hV-Mh)

Answer (score 1):

1. How to save the model in the previously uploaded directory path? => You can use any of the below commands,

   ```
    `model.save_weights('./Weights/Weights')` or 
    `tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model` or 
     `model.save`
   ```
2. How to get weights? => We can Load the Weights using any of the below commands:

   ```
   model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5') or         
   keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5') or

   tf.keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model
   ```
3. I have some csv file as the same used for modeling but without class. how can I estimate the classes with this model? => One of the ways to do it is to iterate the below code for each instance of CSV data Label.

   ```
   ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
   ```

Fore more information, you can refer to the below links:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model